# why is only direct initialization prohibited for class member, not for local variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, most-vexing-parse

with respect to c++11 syntax, I understood that direct initialization of class member is not allowed(most vexing parse). I referred to this posting :

[Why class data members can't be initialized by direct initialization syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696605/why-class-data-members-cant-be-initialized-by-direct-initialization-syntax)

but I did not catch any clues about why local variable is not the case. for example,

```
int main(){
   int a(0); //no compile error
   return 0;
}
```

for above code, compiler doesn't report error and compile this successfully.

Any comments will be very helpful.

Comment: The answer you link shows an example of ambiguity in the class member case. There is no ambiguity in the local variable case because local variables do not see declarations *below*, while class member initialisation sees all other class members, including those declared below.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. That could be an answer, pretty much verbatim :)