# C++17 inline static member class variable error with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

Given this test fragment:

```
class Member
{
};

class MemberNoDefault
{
public:
    MemberNoDefault(int x) {}
};

class Owner
{
    inline static Member member1;
    inline static Member member2();
    inline static MemberNoDefault member3(10);
    static MemberNoDefault member4;
};

MemberNoDefault Owner::member4(10);
```

This fails when compiling with GCC 9.3 on the line with `member3` where it attempts to use a constructor with an argument. The errors are:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

Shouldn't this work? This compiles successfully if I comment out the line with `member3`.

Comment: Note that this constraint has nothing to do with whether the variable is `inline` or `static`.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not a valid way to initialise a member inside the class definition.

You have to use brace-initialisation, or (where valid), an `=`:

```
inline static MemberNoDefault member3a{10};
inline static MemberNoDefault member3b = 10;
```

In this example, aggregate initialisation will work for you too:

```
inline static MemberNoDefault member3c = {10};
```

This is because the parentheses version of initialisation can be too easily confused with a function declaration (like how your `member2` is actually a function), and [they didn't want to make that mistake again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28696741/4386278). Although, personally, I think adding this inconsistency just made it worse.