# Passing parameters to template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

In C++ I am having trouble passing parameters to the constructor for a template class.
it works when I instantiate from a function; but if I instantiate from a class, it gives "error C2059: syntax error: 'string'"
this is my very trimmed down example (names have been changed to protect the incent).
I am currently have std:latest enabled in Visual Studio 2019 and I've tried in 2017 as well.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class cap
{
public:
    cap() : p(new(T)) {}

    cap(const std::string& sfile, const std::string& sfunc, int line)
        : m_file(sfile), m_func(sfunc), m_line(line) {}

    ~cap() {
        delete p;
        std::cout << "object freed: created in " << m_func << " line " << m_line << " of " << m_file;
    }

private:
    T*            p{nullptr};
    std::string   m_file;
    std::string   m_func;
    int           m_line{0};
};

void foo()
{
    cap<int> foo1("file", "func", 5);   //<< compiles okay
}
class bar
{
    cap<int> foo1("file", "func", 5);   //<< "syntax error: 'string'"
};
```

IntelliSense says "expected a type specifier" when I hover the params used inside the class

My end goal is to have a macro to instantiate the object; passing in the location in source.The object thus knows where it was created.

```
#define CAP(type,var) cap<type> var(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__)

CAP(somestruct, myvar);

// expands to:
cap<somestruct> myvar("file.cpp", "myfunc", 50);
```

Comment: please provide a [mre], the code you've posted contains errors but not the error in your question

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and fix it so that it is a [mre]. The shown code will not compile for many other reasons, unrelated to your question. Although the issue seems straightforward, in the past questions that failed to show a [mre] turned out to have other issues that were the real problem, so time spent answering them was a waste. Please show the real code with the claimed issue, that meets all requirements of a [mre], instead of made-up code.

Comment: if this is your code: https://godbolt.org/z/jj8rsb then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696605/why-class-data-members-cant-be-initialized-by-direct-initialization-syntax

Comment: Thank you @AlanBirtles for being smart enough to add two obvious includes.

since I was concerned about the constructor failing and I was confusing 'passing parameters to a function' with 'initialization of something', I did not find the answer you've quoted.

https://godbolt.org/  is cool.  Thank you also for this tip.

peace be with you

Comment: @ThomasOatman no, i had to make quite a few other changes to get your code to fail in the way you said it did

Answer (score 1):

For in-class initialization use the uniform initialization:

```
class bar
{
    cap<int> foo1{"file", "func", 5};
};
```

@Alan has already provided a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696605/why-class-data-members-cant-be-initialized-by-direct-initialization-syntax) for why direct initialization using `()` don't work. It's also known as the C++ most vexed parse.

Comment: Many thanks  @The-Philomath for making the answer concise.