# Why can't I create an object inside a C++ class without specifying its class twice?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I apologize in advance in case I am using improper terms or in case I am simply ignoring something obvious, but I am not completely confident with C++ yet and I really cannot explain this error.

I am using GCC v12.1.0

If I define a class

```
class Class2
{
  public:

  Class2(int n) {a=n; b=n+1; c=n-1;} // Just to do something with n
  int Func() {return a+b+c;} // Just to return something
  int a=0,b=0,c=0;
}
```

And then I define another class which shall contain a Class2 object in its data:

```
class Class1
{
  public:
  
  void Func(int n) {a=n; b=b+1; c=a-b;} // Just to do something
  int Get() {return a+b+c;}¡// Just to return something

  int a=0,b=0,c=0;
  
  Class2 obj(35);
}
```

When I compile I get the error :

*expected identifier before '(' token*

and also

*expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant*

at the line where I try to create 'obj'.

Instead if I create it this way

```
Class2 obj = Class2(35)
```

it compiles fine.
What does NOT make sense to me is that I CAN instead create it eg. in main() this way, but NOT in the class data:

```
int main()
{
  Class2 obj(35);
  ...
}
```

and it compiles fine.

What am I ignoring here ?

Comment: `Class2 obj{35};`

Comment: You are not ignoring anything, you are simply unaware of how complicated C++ grammar's really is, and what its many surprises are. This is one of them.

Comment: @Fantastic Mr Fox, can you explain the MVP ambiguity? I don't see how the offending line can be interpreted as a function declaration.

Comment: This SO Question and accepted answer explain it nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696605/why-class-data-members-cant-be-initialized-by-direct-initialization-syntax. In essence, the compiler error makes it look like a "most vexing parse" issue, but in fact direct initialization in a member declaration is explicitly forbidden by the standard to avoid possible parsing ambiguity. So I suppose this question could be marked a duplicate.

Comment: @Mike Vine apparently using the {} works and the constructor gets called correctly, despite it is not intuitive at all to me. I will also read the other question which joergbrech pointed to. Thanks